# zustand store - variable initilization with new map , not working

Tags: reactjs, store, zustand

Trying to create something like this in zustand store -

```
const authorisationStore = (set, get) => ({
  authorisationData: new Map(),
  ..............
```

But when this store variable is retrieved first time in app.js , its value remain as {} instead of map object. My purpose is to check if map is having particular key but once I do authorisationdata.get('djhdg') , it fails saying get is not a function.

Comment: How are you creating your store? How are you accessing `authorisationData` inside your component?

Answer (score 0):

check this: https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/maps-and-sets-usage. but if you are using typescript, I recommend using a Record

Comment: I am using jsx . I trie dchanging to js as well . but no avail. I guess , the way Map is set in your sent link , I am doing similar.